# What is the cause of the InternalOAuthError in my sails.js passport.js implementation?

Tags: javascript, authentication, sails.js, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

I'm trying to implement passport.js authentication in a `Sails.js` app, using the Google OAuth2.0 strategy. I have considered using `sails-generate-auth` and `sails-auth` but they are no longer supported. I have also considered `Waterlock` but it only works with the local, Twitter and Facebook strategies.

The `google()` function below is called when the user presses the 'login with google+' button. The expected behaviour is that the user then gets redirected to a Google page, where they are prompted to authenticate themselves. In actuality, the following error is logged at the marked line. The user object is undefined at that point.

```
InternalOAuthError: Failed to obtain request token (status: 307 data: <HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Temporary Redirect</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Temporary Redirect</H1>
The document has moved <A HREF="https://accounts.google.com/OAuthGetRequestToken">here</A>.
</BODY>
</HTML>
)
```

The function below is located in the `AuthController` and gets called upon clicking the 'login with Google+' button.

```
google(request, response) {
    const google = sails.config.oauth.google;
    passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
            consumerKey: MY_KEY,
            consumerSecret: MY_SECRET,
            callbackURL: 'http://localhost:1337/auth/callback/google',
        }, (token, tokenSecret, profile, done) => {
            //Verify callback: Never appears to get called.
            User.findOrCreate({ providerId: profile.id, provider: 'Google' }).then((user) => {
                request.session.me = user;
                return done(user);
            }).catch(error => {
                sails.log('Failed to log in using Google: ' + error);
            });
        }
    ));

    passport.authenticate('google', {
        failureRedirect: '/login',
        scope: [
            'profile',
        ],
    }, function(error, user) {
        //Gets called, but user is undefined.
        if (error) {
            sails.log('Err: ' + error); //<== Error gets logged here.
        }
        request.logIn(user, function(error) {
            if (error) {
                sails.log('err: ' + error);
                response.view('500');
                return;
            }
            res.redirect('/');
        });
    })(request, response);
},
```

Misc information: Passport is initialized in `config/policies.js`:

```
    '*': [
    passport.initialize(),
    passport.session(),
],
```

My question: What is the likely cause of the error I'm getting?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue using Express, passport, and passport-google-oath. I solved this by switching to[passport-google-oauth20](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth2).

I am not a 100% sure if this is why, but Google seems to have dropped OAuth support quite a while back.

> Important: OAuth 1.0 was officially deprecated on April 20, 2012, and is no longer supported. We encourage you to migrate to OAuth 2.0 as soon as possible.

You'll have to change your Strategy to:

var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://www.example.com/auth/google/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      return cb(err, user);
    });
  }
));
```